# Low Resistance Logic Level MOSFET

Tags: arduino, led, mosfet

What criteria do I need to look for when selecting a power MOSFET. It will be controlled by an Arduino board so it has to be "logic level". In my application I have to control a 12-15VDC resistive load at no more than 20A (a bunch of high powered LEDs). Ideally, I would like to get away without a heat sink but I am not sure if this is realistic. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What's the switching freqency, if any or is it just on-off? If the later, you are better off with a relay.

Comment: Why don't you try a parametric search on Digi-Key or Mouser?

Comment: Why don't you use a common 10V MOSFET with a gate driver circuit?

Comment: Winny, there will be very little switching. It's for controlling outside LED lights and fountain that will only be on in the morning and evening for a few hours and if motion is detected (for the lights) during certain times of the day. I actually have an "8 Relay Module" but each relay can only handle 10A and does not accept my 12AWG wires. I guess I could use block terminals using a short 16AWG wire from the relay to the block terminal and connect the 12AWG wire there. But there is still the limit of 10A.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't need all 8 relay but only 5. Also there is only one load that is more than 10A. Could I put two relay in parallel to switch one load that is about 15A? It doesn't sound like a terribly good idea (and I know for electrical wiring it's not allowed to combines wires for supporting higher currents) but I figured I through it out there. The relays btw are WRD-05VDS-SL-C.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid using a heatsink the FET needs to dissipate less than 1.25W (assuming TO220 case with R<sub>tja</sub>=40ºc/W and 75ºC junction temperature at 25ºC ambient). Watts = I<sup>2</sup>R, so at 20A R<sub>DSON</sub> needs to be less than 1.25/20<sup>2</sup> = 3.125mΩ.

So look for a logic level FET rated for 30V Drain to Source and R<sub>DSON</sub> = 3mΩ or less at 75ºC. Many suppliers websites have a parametric search function that you can use to narrow the field down.

Comment: Bruce, thanks for that info. I will check out Digi-Key and see if they have something. Btw, I am planning to have everything in a plastic box as it will be outdoors (inside the outside kitchen). Is there some formula to approximate the surface to the outside air I need to keep the temperatures in the box down (plastic is not a good heat conductor, unfortunately, so maybe I need to drill some holes).